# How to have different .env file for Grunt for staging/production?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

How can I have a different .env file in my project when compiling my project with Grunt?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use [switchenv](https://github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/switchenv). It's command line utility for quickly switching .env file from Keepass entries (content from the Notes field). I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install --save cross-env`

In your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env PROJECT_ENV=production grunt",
  "dev": "cross-env PROJECT_ENV=development grunt"
}
```

In your grunt file you can use `process.env.PROJECT_ENV` to verify the current environment depending on which script you run.

Comment: I have 3 environment variable files in my config directory. How do I compile the correct environment variable file only?